# Counting the elements of a dynamic list and "evaluating" the solution (Prolog)

Tags: list, prolog, counting, dynamic-list

The predicate, which I've created does not work correctly.
The predicate should count the items of all the facts in the database and "evaluate" them. (I'll explain later what I mean by "evaluation")

E.g. the facts are:

```
:- dynamic listitem /1.
listitem(number).
listitem(letter).
listitem(word).
listitem(sentence).
```

The first predicate, I've created, collects all the facts into one list:

```
members(W) :- bagof(X,listitem(X),W).
```

Now I want to count the items in the list. So I created a general predicate for counting:

```
count([],0).
count([_|L],N) :- count(L,N1), N is N1+1.
```

My next predicated does not work properly. This predicate has to count all the items of the facts above.

```
count_members(U) :- one_list([bagof(X,listitem(X),_W)],U).
```

The problem is, that the database should be dynamic, so that I can add and remove other items. This means, that i cannot ask

```
?- count([number,letter,word,sentence],N)
```

as the facts might have changed.

And the last step, that does not work at all, because my last predicate is wrong, should be the following: 
Writing "all_members(X)" prolog should return an evaluation. E.g. prolog should return "X = four items" for the query "all_members(X)", if the number of items in the database is 4.
 I hope you've understood my problem. Again, the predicate that I'm searching is "all_members(X)". The other predicates I've created should help me creating the actual one.

I'll be very happy if you could help me finding the solution to my problem! (otherwise I won't be able to fall asleep tonight...)
Thanks!!

EDIT:

Sorry, I forgot to write my definition for one_list. My thought was to make e.g. a list looking like this:

```
 [[number], [letter], [word]]
```

to a list looking like this:

```
[number, letter, word, list]

one_list(X,[X]) :- \+ is_list(X).
one_list([],[]).
one_list([X|Xs],Zs) :- one_list(X,Y), one_list(Xs,Ys), append(Y,Ys,Zs).
```

Comment: You are actually really damn close to your solution. Just two lines. how is one_list defined? i.e., what have you tried so far?

Comment: @ChristianF I edited my question. kind of forgot to write the definition down^^

Comment: Why so complicated? You already have your list (members(X)), now all you need to do is to count it, no?

Comment: `count_members(U) :- 
      members(W),
      count(W,U).`

That's how Prolog's predicates are composed.

Comment: You don't need `count/2`. You can just use `length/2` built in predicate for the length of a list.

Comment: Also, in SWI Prolog, you can use `flatten/2` which I think does what you're trying to do with `one_list/2`.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some confusion in your question.

To count number of `facts/1` if your database (which works as expected even if there are no `facts` currently in the database, as long as `facts` is declared as `dynamic`):

```
?- findall(X, facts(X), Xs), length(Xs, L).
```

Note that you can't say `length(findall(...), L)` because Prolog has predicates, not functions (as pointed out by Will Ness in the comments to your question)!

Creating a list of lists is strange and unnecessary. I don't quite understand why you need it (please elaborate if I am missing something important).

Using `flatten/2` is not a crime but it usually points to a poor design decision.